# Is branching a required feature of currying?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

When writing an implementation of a curry function, is it a requirement to be able to branch?

Usage example in Javascript:

```
var foo = function (a, b) { console.log(a, b); },
x = curry(foo),
y = x('bar'); // An example of branching

x('baz'); // -> 'bar baz'
y('qux'); // - > 'bar qux'
```

The example here is showing that we call our curried function the first time with the value `bar` and store the resulting function in variable `y`.

My question then is: Should we be able to operate on `y` (passing new arguments) independently from further operations applied to `x` (in this case passing `baz` as the next argument).

If you're unsure what currying is, here's what Wikipedia has to say:

> In mathematics and computer science, currying is the technique of
>   translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments
>   (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions,
>   each with a single argument (partial application).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

**Update:**

Another way of asking this question is to say: Should a curried function simply maintain it's current state and return no value other than when the final argument is applied, or should each call result in the return of a new function encapsulating all previously applied arguments?

Comment: Can you brief about the curry function? I suppose I've vague idea of what branching means. P.S, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: If you're not familiar with currying then you probably won't have an answer to my question (which is about implementing it). I've added Wikipedia's description anyway.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why the downvote. Perhaps the example isn't clear enough?

Comment: I've added a further description under the code example to help clear things up. The close votes appear to be because it's unclear what I'm asking. Perhaps it's clear now?

Comment: Why should `x("baz")` say `bar baz`? `x(single_arg)` should return a function, no matter how many times it's called...

Comment: When the final argument is passed to the curried function, the function should execute, should it not?

Comment: @JamieDixon: it should return the value when all the remaining parameters are passed; if less parameters are passed it should simply return a new independent closure waiting for less parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is normally meant with currying is that calling a function with less than the expected number of parameters will return a function that expects the remaining missing parameters.

It should **not** accumulate state on the function object...

```
f = curry(function(x, y, z) { return x+y+z; });

g = f(1)  // --> <func>
h = g(2)  // --> <func>
h(3)      // --> 6  (computed from 1+2+3)
g(10, 20) // --> 31 (computed from 1+10+20)
```

currying is even used in pure functional languages where you don't actually have the concept of mutable state.

Comment: Ok great. It looks like I'm misunderstanding the use of the curried function. I was under the impression that I should be able to apply the remaining arguments to the function outside of a set of chained calls. `x('foo'); x('bar')` It seems that's not a requirement.